# Cannot open a csv file from a & input tags in IE, works in FF & chrome

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I have a piece of java script code which outputs the following button to my webpage:

```
<a href='data:application/csv;charset=UTF-8, " + encodeURIComponent(output) + "' download='myFilename.csv' ><input id='Button1' type='button' value='Title' /></a>
```

'Output' is my string, which along with the code above works in Firefox and Chrome: opening as a csv file in excel, but won't work at all in IE (I eventually need 9-11 to work, but just 10/11's fine for a start). When I click on the button in IE I get the 'webpage cannot be displayed' message.

Any thoughts?

Comment: IE doesn't support the download attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `datauri` is only partially supported by IE.

You can't reference any file but images, stylesheets and since IE10 javascript.
If you want to deliver your CSV, you have to use a server-side script which generates the CSV on the fly.

Source: http://caniuse.com/datauri

I can give you examples on how to create CSV files with PHP or other languages on the fly if you want to.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately we wanted to avoid server side as we can't move the data out of the users browser because of the data protection act.  Presumably the server-side scripts would pull the data into the server?

Comment: You may send the CSV from the client to the script and the script will generate a CSV and stream it to the user. You don't have to store the CSV file (nor the data any user sent) on the server. Also: you could use the script only as a fallback for the IE-family.

Comment: That _“(all of them)”_ is actually not true. IE 8 had a limit of max. 32 KB, and IE <= 9 limited the type to “non-navigable” types, i.e. mostly images and stylesheets, but not f.e. JavaScript. But from IE 10 on, there should be no such problems.

Comment: Everything I've seen says it should work, but I can't make it work. i can't see what I'm doing wrong, I've tried changing mime types, but it either errors (as above) or the button simply doesn't respond when I click it.

Comment: Did you try getting css files using datauris in ie? That should work according to caniuse.con

Comment: I don't have any css files.  I write the program, then someone else does the design and writes the css to style the elements I've used.

Comment: Just to test if your datauri syntax is right. Anyways. I will try to write an example php script as soon as I get home. I'm gonna edit my post to reflect changes.

Comment: Just noticed your syntax error in the datauri string. Right at the download=' part. That could be an issue as well. Does your code work in the latest version of internet explorer?

Comment: No, it doesn't work in any version of IE.  What syntax error?

Comment: Right before 'myFilename.csv' you're closing the href attribute of your link tag. You should use double quotes there. Try changing the single quotes to double quotes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57936/discussion-between-louise-and-praszyk).